# Is my object oriented assembly right?

Tags: object, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

It's been some times that I started learning assembly and I often use object oriented concepts in my programs. I started doing this once I understood assembly well enough to imagine how objects work in machine code, but I do not know if my method is right or not.

Here is what my method looks like :
1. I define constants representing the relative adresses of each member of a class using the assembler constant directive (here gas x86-64).

```
.equ HUMAN_ID,0
.equ HUMAN_AGE,8
.equ HUMAN_NAME,16
.equ HUMAN_SIZE,24 # Size of object is 24 bytes
```

2. I allocate memory for the object and save the address in a pointer memory location.

```
movq $HUMAIN_SIZE,%rcx
call malloc # I avoid getting into systems specifics so I use C library
movq %rax,pointer
```

3. To access it, I dereference the pointer and use the relative address of a member to access it.

```
movq pointer,%rbx
movq $25,HUMAN_AGE(%rbx) # Set age to 25
movq HUMAN_AGE(%rbx),%rax # Get age into rax
```

Is this right? Do you have any advice? Thank you

Comment: _"Is this right?"_ Does it work? If you have working code that you want others to review you should probably ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. If your code doesn't work you need to provide more information about the issue(s) you're experiencing.

Comment: That's not object oriented code, that's simply a struct.

Comment: @Jester - C++ is pretty much that: A structure with a function lookup/jump table after the data section.

Comment: @FrankC. there is no function pointer here, no vtable, no inheritance, no casting, no nothing. This as written is just how to use a struct.

Comment: Yes you are correct so far but my read that @Henri is warming up to providing that. Of course if I am wrong then you must be right!

Comment: @Michael I have working code but my uncertainty is about my code structure and not the code itself.

Comment: The beauty of assembly is that it is unstructured, it's up to you to make structures out of it. However if you feel the need for more and more structures till the point you would like to have some "syntax sugar", then it's time to move to a higher level. Said that, your coding is pretty nice in my opinion, but as Jester said it's nothing new, just a struct (and, still in my opinion, very far from C++).